# getSignedUrl giving "SigningError: Failure from metadata server"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Functions with an HTTP trigger to create an endpoint for an API call. This endpoint is using the `getSignedUrl` function from the Cloud Storage package. I wanted to return a signed URL so the client can `PUT` to that URL to upload a file.

I'm getting inconsistent behavior with this API. Sometimes I will get back a URL from the function. Then I tried to update the bucket name, and I get this error:

```
{ SigningError: Failure from metadata server.
at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/src/file.js:1715:16
at getCredentials (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js:264:9)
at googleAuthClient.getCredentials (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js:148:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7) message: 'Failure from metadata server.' }
```

If I change the bucket name back, I still see this error. I've tried different things such as deploying from the terminal. That gave me the same error. I also created the function with the browser, and that started to work. After I tried updating the bucket name, it stopped working.

From googling around, I'm thinking this is a permission or ACL issue, but I'm not sure how to confirm it. The documentation says that functions run using `<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` service account, which I can confirm in the general tab of the function. I can see in IAM that this service account has the `Service Account Token Creator`, which says:

> Impersonate service accounts (create OAuth2 access tokens, sign blobs or JWTs, etc).

The documentation for `getSignedUrl` says:

> In those environments, we call the signBlob API to create a signed URL. That API requires either the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform scope, so be sure they are enabled.

I feel like this should be enough for it to work. I don't know how to explicitly check for scopes.

The only other thing I've tried is to run `sign-blob` from the terminal. I ran this:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts sign-blob --iam-account=<my-project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com input.file output.file
```

and I get back this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.sign-blob) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/my-project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.

I don't know how to check that my service account has this permission. I've tried looking for it in IAM on the website, the `gcloud` terminal program, and the permissions set on my buckets.

Here is the code for my function:

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

exports.getSignedUrl = (req, res) => {

    if(req.method === 'POST') {

        // Perform any authorization checks here to assert
        // that the end user is authorized to upload.

        const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket-name');
        const myFile = myBucket.file(req.body.filename);
        const contentType = req.body.contentType;

        // This link should only last 5 minutes
        const expiresAtMs = Date.now() + 300000;
        const config = {
            action: 'write',
            expires: expiresAtMs,
            contentType: contentType
        };

        myFile.getSignedUrl(config, function(err, url) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500).end();
                return;
            }
            res.send(url);
        });
    } else {
        res.status(405).end();
    }
}
```

Has anyone seen this before, or know why this is happening? Or do you know how I can check if my service account has these permissions or scopes? I feel like this may be a bug in GCP, but it's likely that I'm missing something. I've been stuck on this for a while, and I'd appreciate any help you may have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found out that `@google-cloud/storage` version `1.6.0` was giving me this behavior. I downgraded to `1.5.2` and it started to work.

I opened up a GitHub issue for this: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/150

Answer (score 12):

I solved it by adding "Cloud Functions Service Agent" role to my "App Engine default service account" service account.

Go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam

[find "Cloud Functions Service Agent"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na4Y3.png)
[manage roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xA9x.png)

I got guided with screen clips in @rscotten comment: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/150

Comment: It's always better to add full explanation than links

Comment: right, I just wanted to credit the @rscotten solution

Comment: This worked, although it was very hard to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @jsambuo this should be the accepted answer